# Jsoup select multiple class

Tags: android, jsoup, парсер

```
<div class="news_content"> <div class="nc_columns clear"> <div class="ncl_left"> <h2 class="b-article__lead">На побережье Каспийского моря не видно привычного оживления, плохая погода отпугнула посетителей. Владельцы и арендаторы объектов общепита и досуга несут убытки.</h2><div class="b-article__text"><p><strong>БАКУ, 1 авг&nbsp;&mdash; Sputnik. </strong>В связи с&nbsp;нестабильными погодными условиями резко уменьшилось количество посетителей кафе и&nbsp;ресторанов, расположенных на&nbsp;берегу моря. Ситуация вызывает серьезное беспокойство у&nbsp;хозяев этих заведений, и&nbsp;в особенности у&nbsp;тех предпринимателей, что арендуют объекты.</p><p>По имеющейся информации, на&nbsp;абшеронских пляжах аренда объекта составляет минимум 15 тысяч манатов за&nbsp;сезон. Учитывая, что с&nbsp;начала лета погода держится очень нестабильная, понять арендаторов можно.</p><p>Однако, как&nbsp;в этой ситуации поступают предприниматели, как&nbsp;они рассчитываются за&nbsp;аренду? Корреспондент Sputnik решил ознакомиться с&nbsp;ситуацией на&nbsp;месте.</p><p><img class="" title="Развлекательные объекты, а также кафе и рестораны Шиховского пляжа бьют тревогу &ndash; нет клиентов" src="http://sputnik.az/images/40661/12/406611202.jpg" alt="Развлекательные объекты, а также кафе и рестораны Шиховского пляжа бьют тревогу &ndash; нет клиентов" width="705" height="375" /></p><p><img class="" title="Одно из таких мест &ndash; развлекательный центр Min bir gecə" src="http://sputnik.az/images/40661/12/406611277.jpg" alt="Одно из таких мест &ndash; развлекательный центр Min bir gecə" width="705" height="375" /></p><p><img class="" title="Открытый ресторан и диско-бар заведения полностью пустует" src="http://sputnik.az/images/40661/10/406611091.jpg" alt="Открытый ресторан и диско-бар заведения полностью пустует" width="705" height="375" /></p><p><img class="" title="В Эльдорадо, расположенном по соседству, та же ситуация" src="http://sputnik.az/images/40661/10/406611028.jpg" alt="В Эльдорадо, расположенном по соседству, та же ситуация" width="705" height="375" /></p><p><img class="" title="Арендатор Balıq evi Шахрияр Алхасов: Хозяин объекта не берет с нас денег за аренду, потому что видит, какие погодные условия и клиентов нет" src="http://sputnik.az/images/40661/09/406610946.jpg" alt="Арендатор Balıq evi Шахрияр Алхасов: Хозяин объекта не берет с нас денег за аренду, потому что видит, какие погодные условия и клиентов нет" width="705" height="375" /></p><div class="b-inject m-inject-free"><div id="injectCopy" class="b-inject__copy">&copy; SPUTNIK/ FUAD HASANOV</div><div id="injectTitle" class="b-inject__content m-slider">Развлекательные объекты, а также кафе и рестораны Шиховского пляжа бьют тревогу &ndash; нет клиентов</div></div><p>&nbsp;</p><p>Развлекательные объекты, а&nbsp;также кафе и&nbsp;рестораны Шиховского пляжа бьют тревогу &ndash; нет клиентов. Одно из&nbsp;таких мест &ndash; развлекательный центр Min bir gecə, администратор которого по&nbsp;имени Али заявил, что с&nbsp;начала сезона заведение работает с&nbsp;убытками.</p><p class="marker-quote1">"За аренду мы платим из&nbsp;своего кармана. Если улучшится погода, половина наших затрат окупится. Надежда осталась на&nbsp;август",&nbsp;&mdash; говорит администратор.</p><p>В открытом ресторане и&nbsp;диско-баре заведения мы никого не&nbsp;встретили. В "Эльдорадо", расположенном по&nbsp;соседству, та же ситуация. Не было клиентов ни&nbsp;на пляже, ни&nbsp;в ресторане.<br />Мы поговорили с&nbsp;двумя сотрудниками объекта, которые рассказали, что клиентов этим летом почти не&nbsp;бывает, и&nbsp;по этой причине уволены многие сотрудники.</p><p>А в&nbsp;ресторане Balıq evi мы столкнулись с&nbsp;интересной ситуацией. Вот что сказал арендатор Шахрияр Алхасов: "Мы очень довольны хозяином этого объекта. Он не&nbsp;берет с&nbsp;нас денег за&nbsp;аренду, потому что видит, какие погодные условия и&nbsp;клиентов нет. Он хороший человек".</p><p>В соседнем же Aqua park вообще не&nbsp;удалось найти не&nbsp;только клиентов, но&nbsp;и сотрудников.</p><p>Одним словом, в&nbsp;нынешнем году ситуация на&nbsp;прибрежных объектах, без&nbsp;преувеличения, плачевная для&nbsp;их хозяев и&nbsp;арендаторов.</p><p>Интересно и&nbsp;иронично высказался на&nbsp;данную тему экономист Натиг Джафарли. Вот что опубликовал эксперт на&nbsp;своей странице в&nbsp;социальной сети: "Мой дорогой брат &ndash; хозяин объекта на&nbsp;берегу моря: ты продавал воду стоимостью 40 гяпиков за&nbsp;2 маната, чайник чая по&nbsp;30 гяпиков за&nbsp;10 манатов, арбуз в&nbsp;1,5 маната за&nbsp;15 манатов, жареную курицу по&nbsp;3 маната &ndash; за&nbsp;40 манатов. Не думал ли ты тогда, что проклятия тысяч клиентов приведут к&nbsp;тому, что на&nbsp;Абшероне на&nbsp;долгие годы летом не&nbsp;будет летней погоды?!".</p><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
```

Как спарсить `<div class="b-article__text">`

Answer (score 2):

```
    String html = "<div class=\"news_content\"> ... <div class=\"b-article__text\"> B-ARTICLE-TEXT </div></div>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Elements el = doc.getElementsByClass("b-article__text");
    String text = el.text();
    System.out.println(text);
```

или

```
    String html = "<div class=\"news_content\"> ... <div class=\"b-article__text\"> B-ARTICLE-TEXT </div></div>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Elements el = doc.getElementsByClass("b-article__text");
    String text = el.html();
    System.out.println(text);
```